# AdWhirl implementation in iPhone Cocoa touch

Tags: iphone, adwhirl

i'm starting to implement AdWhirl in my application. i follow the instructions which is belong to adwhirl but i cant see any ad in my application.i add the following methods in my viewcontroller class

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
 AdWhirlView *adView=[AdWhirlView requestAdWhirlViewWithDelegate:self];
 [self.view addSubview:adView];
}

-(NSString *) adWhirlApplicationKey{
 return @"myAdWhirlKey";
}

-(UIViewController *) viewControllerForPresentingModalView{
 return self;
}
```

i doesn't display anything. please help how to implement AdWhirl

Comment: Please take the time to format the code in your question using the editor tools. (It's the "{}" icon for future reference.)

Comment: Your implementation looks correct on the first sight. And I don't know if you could solve your issues in the meantime but maybe it helps if you increase the loglevel of adwhirl. put `AWLogSetLogLevel(AWLogLevelDebug);` in your code to do so.

Answer (score 1):

you need to see AdWhirl tutorial and you can download it from here
[Tutorial](https://adwhirl-with-iad.googlecode.com/files/AdWhirl_pro.zip)

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the AdWhirl SDK key in adWhirlApplicationKey delegate to work. check the link to get adWhirlkey... http://chandanshetty01.blogspot.com/2011/06/integrating-ads-to-ios-apps-using.html